# deleting log files with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which deletes log files but not the locked ones. The files are open with notepad++. Not sure what else to add. Any suggestions?

$logpath = "C:\logs"
Get-ChildItem $logpath -recurse | Remove-Item -force

Comment: "*Not sure what else to add. Any suggestions?*" - Explain what you want to achieve. Go ask the person running Notepad++ to close the files when they're done looking at them? Edit your server policies to auto-logoff after a few minutes of inactivity?

Comment: Are you comfortable with losing all of the changes that someone may have made?  Who's got them open?  Why are they looking at logfiles?  Do they need the data from within?  While doubtful, @TessellatingHeckler is right - is this the route you really want to go down?

Comment: I'd also suspect something else has a lock on the files (e.g., the program doing the logging). I delete temp/test files all the time that are open in Notepad++ and I am never prevented from doing so. Notepad++ just points out they no longer exist and asks if I want to keep them in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here would probably be to use the sysinternals application [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to get the process ID of the file that is locked and then close that process before continuing with the deletion.

Comment: .. no mention of losing any changes that have been made?  While this is technically an answer, it's not a good idea without this caveat being clear.  It's not yet understood why the asker would encounter someone with logfiles open in Notepad++, yet.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get it to work by adding a pipeline to exclude the folder and its contents instead of deleting it.